# incomplete output variable stored

Tags: bash, awk, emc

im actually working with a small script, this script uses a comand from a NAS EMC Storage, the main idea is to storage and output variable and use it for other command.

```
nameserver="$(nas_server -list -all | awk 'NR == 3 {print $6}')"


serverparam1="$(server_param "$nameserver" -facility NDMP -list)"

echo "$serverparam1"
```

So.. this command `nas_server -list -all | awk 'NR == 3 {print $6}` returns "server_3"

the idea is to storage the name "server_3" and use it in this other command:

```
server_param server_3 -facility NDMP -list
```

The problem with all this stuff, is that the output print is not "server_3" only get "ver_3" i don't know why this is happening.

This is the ouput of the terminal:

```
[nasadmin@xxxx ~]$ ./test.sh
 : ver_3
 : unknown hostver_3
```

This is the output from server_param

```
    [nasadmin@xxxx ~]$ server_param server_3 -facility NDMP -list
server_3 :
param_name                       facility  default     current   configured
maxProtocolVersion                  NDMP          4          4
scsiReserve                         NDMP          0          0
DHSMPassthrough                     NDMP          0          0
CDBFsinfoBufSizeInKB                NDMP       1024       1024
noxlt                               NDMP          0          0
bufsz                               NDMP        128        128
convDialect                         NDMP     8859-1     8859-1
concurrentDataStreams               NDMP          4          4
includeCkptFs                       NDMP          1          1
md5                                 NDMP          1          1
snapTimeout                         NDMP          5          5
dialect                             NDMP
forceRecursiveForNonDAR             NDMP          0          0
excludeSvtlFs                       NDMP          1          1
tapeSilveringStr                    NDMP         ts         ts
portRange                           NDMP 1024-65535 1024-65535
snapsure                            NDMP          0          0
v4OldTapeCompatible                 NDMP          1          1

    [nasadmin@xxxx ~]$ nas_server -list -all
id      type  acl  slot groupID  state  name
1        1    0     2              0    server_2
2        4    0     3              0    server_3

id       acl  server    mountedfs       rootfs  name
1        0    1         17              13      TEST_VDM-1
2        0    1         16              14      TEST_VDM-2
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you get if you hex-dump it? `./test.sh | xxd`

Comment: Sounds like `\r` somewhere in the output

Comment: Actually, make that `./test.sh 2>&1 | xxd`. We want to get stderr, too.

Comment: Can you show us the output of `nas_server -list -all`?

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem on a similar EMC NAS (VG2). Also the output of `server_param movername -facility NDMP -list` is a formatted table. Could you post the complete `test.sh` script? And also explain what info are you trying to get at the end.

Comment: As @choroba suggested, your input file contains trailing control-Ms. Run dos2unix or similar on it before running your command.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov it's a EMC VNX.

Comment: @EdMorton could you show me some example of what you propouse? or a link ?

Comment: @Jack done, updated the main question.

Comment: Just search for `dos2unix` in the archives of this site or google it. You'll find thousands of hits, pick any one. The issue is your input lines end in `string\r\n` instead of just `string\n` and `\r` causes the cursor to jump back to the start of the line when you print it so you get some output then the cursor jumps back thanks to the `\r` and then you get the rest, overwriting what was already printed. Pipe the output of your command to `| cat -v` to see the `\r`s as `^M`s.

Comment: Need the output of `nas_server`, not `server_param`.

Comment: @Jack lol, done.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with the others about the `\r` lurking in the output of `nas_server`.  If your installation does not have `dos2unix`, you can use `tr -d '\r'` instead.  Put that in the pipeline before `awk` and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me

```
nameserver="$(nas_server -list -all  |  awk 'NR == 5 {print $6}')"

nameserver1="$(dos2unix $nameserver)"

serverparam0="$(server_param "$nameserver0" -facility NDMP -list)"

echo "$serverparam0"
```